# Child view controllers in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a view controller with 3 child view controllers and a `UIScrollView` within the main view. The setup code for the VerticalScrollViewController is below.

```
func setupScrollView() {
        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.bounces = false
        
        let view = (
            x: self.view.bounds.origin.x,
            y: self.view.bounds.origin.y,
            width: self.view.bounds.width,
            height: self.view.bounds.height
        )
        
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: view.x, y: view.y, width: view.width, height: view.height)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        // These constraints don't seem to affect it and I did try and set the scroll view constraints to the parent views safe area, but that did not work either
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
                                     scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
                                     scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
                                     scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)])
        
        
        let scrollWidth: CGFloat  = view.width
        var scrollHeight: CGFloat

        scrollHeight  = 3 * view.height
        topVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.width, height: view.height)
        middleVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.height, width: view.width, height: view.height)
        bottomVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 2 * view.height, width: view.width, height: view.height)
            
        addChild(topVc)
        addChild(middleVc)
        addChild(bottomVc)
                
        scrollView.addSubview(topVc.view)
        scrollView.addSubview(middleVc.view)
        scrollView.addSubview(bottomVc.view)
            
        topVc.didMove(toParent: self)
        middleVc.didMove(toParent: self)
        bottomVc.didMove(toParent: self)
            
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = middleVc.view.frame.origin.y
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight)
}
```

For some reason, the view is offset at the top by about 50 points. By that I mean the view for my view controllers starts at the very top of the view of the selected scroll view frame. This causes the notch on iPhone X  and later to cover a part of it.

My question is this: How do I add 3 view controllers to my scroll view and line up the top with the UIScrollView safe area?

I have tried activating the constraints for all 3 VCs UIViews, but that did not work as expected. The `middleVc` was fine but when I would scroll, the top and bottom just *slid* behind the `middleVc` UIView. I am sure this is something that I am missing on the constraints side, but I have not been able to use the view debugger to pin point which constraints and where I should add them. I looked at a few questions here on SO, but most of them dealt with Storyboards and I am doing everything programatically.

Comment: Is your UIScrollView underneath the notch area?  What is your UIScrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior set to?  [off topic, but having many child view controllers is a bit unusual unless you are implementing something structural like something like a UIPageViewController or UITabViewController  could be really appropriate in your case, but it is unusual]

Comment: I have not looked into `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior  ` yet. The scroll view extends above the notch are and below the home indicator as well. 

The idea behind the 3 child view controllers is the only way I’ve seen the behavior I want implemented. I’m trying to create 3 different parts of my app that are accesible through swiping gestures.

Comment: Sounds like you want a UIPageViewController with a transition style of .scroll

Comment: That solution may be easier than trying to figure out this offset issue. Thanks!